# How do i navigate to another view through a button in a NSTableCell?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uibutton, nstableviewcell

I have got a Button in a custom table cell, with which I want to navigate to a view. But this view has to be different to the view you get if you simply press the TableCell. Has anybody solved this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can push another view in button click event

Eg:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```